# How to install cloudera manager on Ubuntu (12.0.4)-32-bit

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera

I am having a 32-bit Ubuntu version and seems like the latest Cloudera Manager does support only 64-bit.Has anyone installed CDH4 and the cloud era manager on Ubuntu (12.0.4) 32 bit ?.Can you please let me know how to do the same.

Comment: Even I am also trying to install cloudera CDH4 on Ubuntu 32 bit but getting some error. Were you able to install it on your system?

Comment: Nope I was only able to install basic apache hadoop components.Let me know if there is a way to install cloudera CDH4 on ubuntu 32-bit

Answer (score -1):

I believe CDH4 is not supported for 32bit Ubuntu.. 32 bit is supported for 32bit RHEL 6.2